# Global FormClosing/Load events in .NET

Tags: vb.net, events, global, formclosing

I'm using VB.NET 4.7.2

I have a multi-form application and I'm coding the "Window" menu on top to show open forms so the user can easily switch (now that Win11 has forced combining applications on the taskbar).

I need each open form to be able to handle the FormOpening and Load events generated by other forms.  My current solution is to handle those events locally in each form, which then triggers a custom global event that any other form can handle.

But that's a little tedious - is it possible for one form to handle another form's closing or opening without this workaround?

Comment: *I need each open form to be able to handle the FormOpening and Load events generated by other forms*: why? What has this do to with *I'm coding the "Window" menu*?

Comment: The Window menu shows all current open forms. So in order to stay updated it needs to know when other forms open or close

Comment: Your comment made me think I don't need to catch forms opening and closing. I decided instead to make a custom ToolStripMenuItem class that just refreshes the open windows when OnDropDownShow fires

Comment: You can do (give or take) what the Menustrip does when the `MdiWindowListItem` is set to a ToolStripMenuItem (and the Container is a MDI Form): loop the `Application.OpenForms` collection and add a ToolStripMenuItem for each when it's opened, remove all when it's closed. When a sub-menu that lists a Form is selected, call the `BringToFront()` method of that Form.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass a standard form to do all the scut work of registering with the shared global and hooking other forms events. You then just need to change the forms header to point at the subclasses type and off you go.